# How to color the area between two arcs with Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, fill

I have to draw the section of a star but I do not know how to fill the area between the arcs I have drawn. Here is the code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [help lines](0,0) grid (10,10);
\draw [thick] (5,0) -- (1,8);
\draw [thick] (5,0) -- (9,8);
\draw [thick] (5,0) ++(60.43:8.94) arc (60.43:116.57:8.94);
\draw [thick] (5,0) ++(63.43:3) arc (63.43:116.57:3) node[left,sloped,rotate=35,font=\footnotesize]{$\approx2\rho_0$};
\draw [thick] (5,0) ++(59:5) arc (59:116.57:5) node[left,sloped,rotate=35,font=\footnotesize]{$\approx0.5\rho_0$};
\draw [thick] (5,0) ++(63.43:7) arc (63.43:116.57:7);
\draw [thick] (5,0) ++(60.43:8.5) arc (60.43:116.57:8.5);
\draw [thick] (5,0) -- (5.35,-0.22);
\draw  [<->](9,7.518) -- (9.175,7.88) node[midway,right,sloped,rotate=-90] {10 cm};;
\draw  [<->](7.43,4.37) -- (9,7.518) node[midway,below,sloped] {(1-2) km};
\draw  [<->](5.175,-0.11) -- (7.43,4.37) node[midway,below,sloped] {(9-12) km};     
\node at (5, 0) [left,rotate=35,font=\footnotesize]{$(3-9)\rho_0$}; 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Diagram produced by the above code which consists of a sector of a circle with several arcs across it, all overlaid on a grid]

I am new to Tikz so I am not very skilled, thank you!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please post your `MWE` in executable format, i.e., from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`

Comment: As you don't have any rep here yet, I've added a screenshot of what your code produces (and included the preamble necessary to get it to compile).  Which area do you want filled, or is it that each band should be filled with a different colour?

Comment: (Thank you Andrew for completing the code and adding a screenshot.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If every part/ring should be filled with a different color you can just draw them from outside in covering the bigger ones partially.

I'm using the `siunitx` package and its `…range` macros.

The *ρ* at the origin is somewhat cheaty since it uses a radius of 0.0001 (i.e 1µm). to get the right orientation for that node.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{range-phrase=\dots, range-units=bracket}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, calc, quotes}
\tikzset{
  Measure/.tip={Latex[] . Bar[sep=+0pt +-.5]},
  pics/Measure/.style args={#1--#2}{code={
    \path[Measure-Measure, midway, auto=right, sloped, draw, pic actions]
      ($(#1)!5pt!-90:(#2)$) -- node[style/.expand once=\tikzpictextoptions]{\tikzpictext}
      ($(#2)!5pt!90:(#1)$);}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[start angle=60, delta angle=60, thick]
\coordinate (O) at (0, 0);
\foreach[count=\i] \r/\t/\c in {
  8.5//red,
  8  //orange,
  6  //yellow,
  4  /\approx 0.5 \rho_0/green,
  2  /\approx 2   \rho_0/blue!50,
  0.001  /\numrange{3}{9}\rho_0/black%
} \draw[fill=\c] (O) -- (\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/start angle}:\r) coordinate (s-\i)
     arc[radius=\r] node[at end, sloped, left]{$\t$} -- cycle;
%\foreach \pair/\t/\s in {
\pic["\qtyrange{9}{12}{\kilo\metre}"] {Measure = O--s-4};
\pic["\qtyrange{1} {2}{\kilo\metre}"] {Measure = s-4--s-2};
\pic["\qty{10}{\centi\metre}" {right, rotate=-90}, arrows={[scale length=.5]}] {Measure = s-2--s-1};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: If not every ring should be filled with a solid color we can just draw each ring and not the whole segment.

Answer (score 1):

Try to adapt to yours needs this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[fill=red] (0,0)--(50:6) arc (50:130:6)--cycle;
        \draw[fill=white] (0,0)--(50:5) arc (50:130:5)--cycle;
        \draw[fill=green] (0,0)--(50:3.5) arc (50:130:3.55)--cycle;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]